# Disabled root login and no root users.. What to do? CentOs 6

Tags: ssh, centos, root, centos-6

So I was undoing some changes here on CentOs 6, and I ended up removing all users who had root access, accept for the root user. But then I realized the root login is disabled, and I just disabled root access for the user I am logged into.

Now I can't modify/access really any file.

What can I do from here? Through FTP it just blocks uploading.

Comment: Do you have physical access to PC? Are you using dm-crypt or any other data encryption? Can you change boot device?

Comment: Actually its my VPS from VMBox.Co so I don't have any physical access.. Am I left to now just re install the entire server?

Comment: Did you tried `single user mode`?

Comment: I don't know how to exactly boot into single user mode, I connect through SSH using putty.

Comment: You need to have access to terminal through some KVM solution.

Comment: Hmm, need a few, I will go and check for access.

Comment: I am provided a Serial Console, it gave me an alt login to log in as root, I can now modify things and fix it. Thanks for reminding me about the KVM Solution :)

Comment: If you still have an account with sudo permissions, you might be able to do something like `sudo bash`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may login as root by editing Grub configuration on system boot, [manual @ centos.org](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Installation_Guide-en-US/s1-rescuemode-booting-single.html) and login in single user mode, then you simply change what you need.

OR

Use KVM (solution in this case) :)